# After first selection box selected, display second result based on first selection result. But not getting any result while POST

Tags: javascript, php

after first selection box selected, display second result based on first selection result. But not getting any result while POST. While I submit the form, system prompt

> "Notice: Undefined index: location in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\auditsystem\calendar\func\scheduleaction.php on line
>   8"

I get the result while display, only show error while submit the form.

func.php

```
 <?php
  include_once('db.php');
  function getTierOne()
  {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM outlet_type")
    or die(mysql_error());

      while($tier = mysql_fetch_array( $result ))

        {
           echo '<option value="'.$tier['id'].'">'.$tier['type'].'</option>';
        }
  }

if(isset($_GET['func'])) {
   drop_1($_GET['drop_var']);
}

function drop_1($drop_var)
{

    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM outlet_type_location WHERE outlet_type_id='$drop_var'")
    or die(mysql_error());

    echo '<select name="location" id="tier_one" onChange="showUP(this.value)" class="form-control">
                <option value=" " disabled="disabled" selected="selected">-Select Outlet location-</option>';
           while($drop_2 = mysql_fetch_array( $result2 ))
            {
              echo '<option value="'.$drop_2['location'].'">'.$drop_2['location'].'</option>';
            }
    echo '</select> ';

}
?>
```

scheduleaction.php (here show error code)

```
<?php

    include_once("db.php");

    $auditor_id                 =     $_POST["auditor"];
    $outlet_type_id             =     $_POST["type"];
    $date                       =   $_POST["date"];
    $outlet_location             =     $_POST["location"];


    echo $auditor_id."<br>";
    echo $outlet_type_id."<br>";
    echo $outlet_location;
    echo $date;
?>
```

Form php

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#wait_1').hide();
        $('#drop_1').change(function(){
          $('#wait_1').show();
          $('#result_1').hide();
          $.get("func/func.php", {
            func: "drop_1",drop_var: $('#drop_1').val()
          }, function(response){
            $('#result_1').fadeOut();
            setTimeout("finishAjax('result_1', '"+escape(response)+"')", 0);
          });
            return false;
        });
    });

    function finishAjax(id, response) {
      $('#wait_1').hide();

      $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
      $('#'+id).fadeIn();
    }
    </script>
  <tr>
                      <label>Oulet Type:</label>
                      <select name="type" id="drop_1" class="form-control">
                      <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">-Click to select-</option>
                            <?php

                            include ("func/db.php");
                            include ("func/func.php");

                            getTierOne();

                            ?>
                      </select>
                      <span id="wait_1" style="display: none;"><img alt="Please Wait" src="ajax-loader.gif"/></span>
                      <span id="result_1" style="display: none;"></span>
                      </tr>
```

Comment: The error is in `scheduleaction.php`. can you post that as well?

Comment: post scheduleaction.php code

Comment: @SandeepNayak scheduleaction.php was Postresult.php :)

Comment: show the code that is getting Postresult.php, clearly you're not sending a value for `location` - as the error states _Undefined index_ **location** _in... on_ **line 8** - and look at line 8

Comment: @HiteshValaAhir just edit my question :)

Comment: @JaromandaX yes, I can't get any value for location.

Comment: where is form code??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju edit my question. sorry

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju please check ya~

Comment: where is the name for select??

Comment: in func.php you starting with select, but in form ur callinh func.php inside select. select inside select??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju I move out the func.php its still not getting location variable.

Comment: after form submit, `var_dump($_POST);` see what values are coming.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju array(3) { ["auditor"]=> string(1) "1" ["type"]=> string(1) "2" ["date"]=> string(10) "1992-11-22" } 

location still not coming.

Comment: add your complete form, there is something wrong in form.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju I post at below the post ya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, only mistake is, `include()` is present outside the form.

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("../connection/connect.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Apex Audit System | Administration Panel</title>
    <!-- Core CSS - Include with every page -->
    <link href="../assets/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../assets/plugins/pace/pace-theme-big-counter.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../assets/css/main-style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Page-Level CSS -->
    <link href="../assets/plugins/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#wait_1').hide();
        $('#drop_1').change(function(){
          $('#wait_1').show();
          $('#result_1').hide();
          $.get("func/func.php", {
            func: "drop_1",drop_var: $('#drop_1').val()
          }, function(response){
            $('#result_1').fadeOut();
            setTimeout("finishAjax('result_1', '"+escape(response)+"')", 0);
          });
            return false;
        });
    });

    function finishAjax(id, response) {
      $('#wait_1').hide();

      $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
      $('#'+id).fadeIn();
    }
    </script>
<body>

<?php
include_once("../assets/template/mainlinks2.php");
include_once("../assets/template/sidebar3.php");
?>        <!--  page-wrapper -->
        <div id="page-wrapper">


            <div class="row">
                 <!--  page header -->
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1 class="page-header">Setup New Schedule</h1>
                </div>
                 <!-- end  page header -->
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <!-- Advanced Tables -->
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                             Assign New Schedule
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="table-responsive">

                             <form action="func/scheduleaction.php" role="form" method="POST" name="form">
            <table>
                  <div class="form-group">

                        <?php

                            include ("func/db.php");
                            include ("func/func.php");
                        ?>
                      <tr>
                      <label>Auditor Name:</label>
                      <select class="form-control" name="auditor">
                                <?php
                                $result =  $db->query("SELECT * FROM auditor");
                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                                {
                                    echo '<option value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["auditor_name"].'</option>';
                                    }
                                echo "</select>";
                                ?>
                  </tr>


                      <tr>
                      <label>Oulet Type:</label>
                      <select name="type" id="drop_1" class="form-control">
                      <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">-Click to select-</option>
                            <?php

                            getTierOne();

                            ?>
                      </select>
                      <span id="wait_1" style="display: none;"><img alt="Please Wait" src="ajax-loader.gif"/></span>
                      <span id="result_1" style="display: none;"></span>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                      <label>Audit Date:</label>
                      <input type="date" name="date" class="form-control" required="required">
                      </tr>
                   <br>
                   <tr>
                   <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Button</button></td>
                   <td><button type="reset" class="btn btn-success">Reset Button</button></td>
                   </tr>

                                        </div>
                             </form>
                             </table>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--End Advanced Tables -->

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end page-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- end wrapper -->


    <!-- Core Scripts - Include with every page -->
    <script src="../assets/plugins/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/plugins/pace/pace.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/scripts/siminta.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: while I try this, error prompt.

Notice: Undefined index: func in C:\xampp\htdocs\auditsystem\calendar\func\func.php on line 20

Comment: Once I change it back everything fine.

Comment: curious about this. Any other solution?

Comment: select should be present inside the form.

Comment: check the line in which error is coming, small thing ll be there.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("../connection/connect.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Apex Audit System | Administration Panel</title>
    <!-- Core CSS - Include with every page -->
    <link href="../assets/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../assets/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../assets/plugins/pace/pace-theme-big-counter.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../assets/css/main-style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- Page-Level CSS -->
    <link href="../assets/plugins/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#wait_1').hide();
        $('#drop_1').change(function(){
          $('#wait_1').show();
          $('#result_1').hide();
          $.get("func/func.php", {
            func: "drop_1",drop_var: $('#drop_1').val()
          }, function(response){
            $('#result_1').fadeOut();
            setTimeout("finishAjax('result_1', '"+escape(response)+"')", 0);
          });
            return false;
        });
    });

    function finishAjax(id, response) {
      $('#wait_1').hide();

      $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
      $('#'+id).fadeIn();
    }
    </script>
<body>
  <?php

  include ("func/db.php");
  include ("func/func.php");
   ?>
<?php
include_once("../assets/template/mainlinks2.php");
include_once("../assets/template/sidebar3.php");
?>        <!--  page-wrapper -->
        <div id="page-wrapper">


            <div class="row">
                 <!--  page header -->
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1 class="page-header">Setup New Schedule</h1>
                </div>
                 <!-- end  page header -->
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <!-- Advanced Tables -->
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                             Assign New Schedule
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="table-responsive">
                             <form action="func/scheduleaction.php" role="form" method="POST" name="form">
                             <table>

                  <div class="form-group">
                      <tr>
                      <label>Auditor Name:</label>
                      <select class="form-control" name="auditor">
                                <?php
                                $result =  $db->query("SELECT * FROM auditor");
                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                                {
                                    echo '<option value="'.$row["id"].'">'.$row["auditor_name"].'</option>';
                                    }
                                echo "</select>";
                                ?>
                  </tr>


                      <tr>
                      <label>Oulet Type:</label>
                      <select name="type" id="drop_1" class="form-control">
                      <option value="" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">-Click to select-</option>
                            <?php

                            getTierOne();

                            ?>
                      </select>
                      <span id="wait_1" style="display: none;"><img alt="Please Wait" src="ajax-loader.gif"/></span>
                      <span id="result_1" style="display: none;"></span>
                      </tr>

                      <tr>
                      <label>Audit Date:</label>
                      <input type="date" name="date" class="form-control" required="required">
                      </tr>
                   <br>
                   <tr>
                   <td><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Button</button></td>
                   <td><button type="reset" class="btn btn-success">Reset Button</button></td>
                   </tr>

                                        </div>
                             </form>
                             </table>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--End Advanced Tables -->

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end page-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- end wrapper -->


    <!-- Core Scripts - Include with every page -->
    <script src="../assets/plugins/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/plugins/metisMenu/jquery.metisMenu.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/plugins/pace/pace.js"></script>
    <script src="../assets/scripts/siminta.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: are you able to see dropdown of location in this form??

Comment: check the answer i have given.

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju still the same bro. aikss

Comment: do you have facebook? I think we contact over there. I can screenshoot for you